# How does the pre/post-increment operator behave before variable allocation?

Tags: c#, operators, operator-precedence

```
int x=3, y=4, n=0;
int n = x * y / --x;
```

This code calculates `n` to be 6, but I thought it'd be 4; since `--x` is a pre-decrement operator and has higher precedence than `*` and `/` so it would be `2 * 4 / 2` I assumed it's `2*4` and not `3*4` as `x` has already been decremented, so what am I missing here? The same question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27933384/why-does-the-pre-post-increment-operator-behave-wrongly) but the answer was PHP-specific.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371118/how-do-the-post-increment-i-and-pre-increment-i-operators-work-in-java

Comment: @kbunarjo That doesn't answer my question.

Comment: x has already been evaluated before it gets to --x, therefore x is still 3.

Comment: But `--` has higher precedence than `*` and therefore `--x` is evaluated before going to `x*y`, isn't that correct?

Comment: I believe that c++ is first evaluates the variable names before doing any arithmetic. Therefore when it comes upon the first x, it evaluates that as 3, and then moves on the the y, and then the --x, which it appropriately decrements. Then it does the arithmetic.

Comment: Are you sure about that? That's C# by the way. Now speaking about C++ I went ahead and tried this in Xcode it gives me a warning: "Unsequenced modification and access to 'x'".

Comment: It has a higher precedence in the fact it decremented before it divided. I wouldn't have expected it to decrement before the multiply because `--x` wasn't to be used until the divide.

Comment: The C# specification is very clear that associativity, precendence, and order of evalution are all different things. Expressions like `x`, `y`, and `--x` are evaluated from left to right. I'm sure there's a duplicate of this question.

Comment: @mike Associativity comes into play when we have two operators with the same precedence. Now what to do you mean by 'evaluated from right t left'? Do you mean associativity? If so they don't have the same precedence, if not then what use is the precedence if operators with different precedence is always evaluated LTR?

Comment: [This article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/05/23/precedence-vs-associativity-vs-order/) is a good one that explains the difference between the three concepts and contrasts C# with C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we compile this code and then inspect it using ildasm, we get the following instructions (translated using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CIL_instructions):

```
 IL_0000:  nop          // I compiled in debug mode, this does nothing
 IL_0001:  ldc.i4.3     // Push 3 onto the stack as int32.  
 IL_0002:  stloc.0      // Pop a value from stack into local variable 0.
 IL_0003:  ldc.i4.4     // Push 4 onto the stack as int32.  
 IL_0004:  stloc.1      // Pop a value from stack into local variable 1.
 IL_0005:  ldloc.0      // Load local variable 0 onto stack.
 IL_0006:  ldloc.1      // Load local variable 1 onto stack.
 IL_0007:  mul          // Multiply values.
 IL_0008:  ldloc.0      // Load local variable 0 onto stack.
 IL_0009:  ldc.i4.1     // Push 1 onto the stack as int32.  
 IL_000a:  sub          // Subtract value2 from value1, returning a new value.
 IL_000b:  dup          // Duplicate the value on the top of the stack.
 IL_000c:  stloc.0      // Pop a value from stack into local variable 0.    
 IL_000d:  div          // Divide two values to return a quotient or floating-point result. 
 IL_000e:  stloc.2      // Pop a value from stack into local variable 2.
 IL_000f:  ret          // Return from method, possibly with a value.
```

This reveals that the expression is evaluated from left to right, even though `--x` precedes `*` and `/`.

This is also documented in the C# language specification (section 7.3 Operators):

> The order of evaluation of operators in an expression is determined by the 
>   precedence and associativity of the operators (§7.3.1).
>
> Operands in an expression are evaluated from left to right. For
>   example, in F(i) + G(i++) * H(i), method F is called using the old
>   value of i, then method G is called with the old value of i, and,
>   finally, method H is called with the new value of i. This is separate
>   from and unrelated to operator precedence.

Comment: Can you please give an example of LTR evaluation not using functions, just operators?

Comment: Your example is one.  The operands are evaluated LTR (`x`, then `y`, then `--x`).  The order of _operations_ is determined by operator precedence but the _operands_ themselves are evaluated left-to-right.

Comment: What @D Stanley wrote was exactly what I was going to say. There is a difference between operands and operators. Operator precedence defines the order in which the operands are processed, but before processing the expression, all operandes are evaluated from left to right, regardless of the operators in the expression.